# Como cambio este Menu para que me verifique los datos guardados en listas y no en variables?

Tags: python

hice este código con un limite de 3 usuario máximo  para registro. El drama que ahora me piden que guarde los nombres y contraseñas en listas y no se como dar el salto además que como me cambia las variables con listas el inicio de sesión  tendría que volverlo hacer y no como hacer que la lista de usuarios me verifique que la contraseña este correcta.

```html
opcion = 0
user = 0
usuario1 = None
usuario2 = None
usuario3 = None
contrasena1 = None
contrasena2 = None
contrasena3 = None

while (opcion != 3):
    print("1. Iniciar Sesión")
    print("2. Registrar Usuario")
    print("3. Salir")

    try:
        opcion = int(input())

    except:
        print("Debe ingresar sólo números")

if (opcion == 1):

    if (user == 0):
        print("Primero debe crear un usuario")

    else:
        var = input("Ingrese ususario: ")

        if (usuario1 == var):
            password = int(input("Ingrese contraseña: "))

        else:
            print("contraseña incorrecta")
```

Comment: ¿Hace unos días no publicaste lo mismo?

Comment: claro , el drama que el problema no era el codigo en si era simplemente cambiar de variables a listas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para no hacer muchos cambios y hacerlo de forma fácil, vamos a definir un diccionario como estructura de dato para almacenar a los usuarios, junto con su contraseña.

Primero creamos un diccionario vacío, en este caso le puse un dato para hacer la prueba.

```py
opcion = 0 #definimos la opcion
#creamos nuestro diccionario
users = {"user":["christian"],"password":["123"]} #pasword almacenado como string
```

En el diccionario especificamos 2 `keys` uno llamado `users`, que será donde se almacenen los usuarios, y otra llamada `password`, donde se almacena la contraseña del usuario. La primera contraseña corresponde al primer usuario, la segunda al segundo y así sucesivamente.

Bueno vamos con el codigo

```py
#ciclo while
while (opcion != 3):
    print("1. Iniciar Sesión")
    print("2. Registrar Usuario")
    print("3. Salir")

    try:
        opcion = int(input())

    except:
        print("Debe ingresar sólo números")

    if (opcion == 1):
        if (len(users)==0): #aqui comprobamos si existen usuarios
            print("Primero debe crear un usuario")

        else:
            var = input("Ingrese ususario: ") #ingresamos el nombre de usuario
            
            if var in users["user"]: #verificamos si esta en la lista de user del diccionario
                #posicion del usuario en la lista
                pos_user = users["user"].index(var) #nos indica en que poscicion esta el usurio
```

Obtenemos la posición del usuario en la lista para poder acceder a su contraseña, como dije si el usuario esta en la posición `0`(la primera), su contraseña estara en la misma posición pero del campo `password`

```py
                ....
                password = input("Ingrese contraseña: ")#pedimos la contraaseña
                if password == users["password"][pos]:#comprobamos
                    print(f"bienvenido usuario {var}")#si son iguales lo dejamos pasar
                    break
                else:
                    print("Contraseña incorrecta")#le decimos que a contraseña fue incorrecta
            else:
                print("usuario incorrecto")
```

tambien podemos definir una estructura de datos de tuplas, donde cada tupla es `(usuario,contraseña)`, no es muy difícil de hacer y tampoco tienes que cambiar todo tu código

**Con tuplas**

Solo inicializamos una lista vacía, la cual contendrá la tupla. En este caso igual le puse un valor

```py
opcion = 0 #definimos la opcion
users = [("christian","123")]
```

El while es igual, asi que nos saltamos a la parte de pedir el usuario y contraseña.

```py
while (opcion != 3):
    ...
      if (opcion == 1):
        if (len(users)==0): #igual verificamos que la lista no este vacia
            print("Primero debe crear un usuario")

        else:
            username = input("Ingrese ususario: ")#ingresamos un usuario
            #aqui lo que hacemos es recorrer la lista y acceder a cada elemento de la tupla
            #le pones un if, para que solo retorna la tupla cuyo username corresponda con el ingresado
            
            user = [us for us in users if us[0]==username]
            #si existe mas de 1 nos devolverá una lista con mas de 1 elemento
            #el código solo tomara evaluara el primer resultado 
 
            #aqui tambien poser verificar que solo exista una tupla
            if user:
                user = user[0] #el username se encuentra en la primera poscicion 
                password = input("Ingrese contraseña: ")
                if password == user[1]:#verificamos la contraseña (segunda posicion)
                    print(f"bienvenido usuario {user[0]}")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Contraseña incorrecta")
            else:
                print("usuario incorrecto")
```

Para hacer que nuestro programa evalúe a todos los usuario (en caso existan varios con un username igual), nos podemos ayudar de un ciclo `for`, pero ese trabajo te lo dejo a ti :)

Answer (score 0):

He creado esta versión de la que ya tienes aplicando listas de listas.
iniciamos opción en 0 para entrar al while, login en false para indicar cuando el usuario inicia sesión, usuarios se inicia en una lista vaciá, lo que sigue hacemos el while con las 3 opciones, la opción 1 inicia sesión, si no hay usuarios indica que debes registrar algún usuario, si hay usuarios entramos a ingresar el usuario y verificar en la lista de usuarios si hay alguna coincidencia, si coincide el usuarios pedimos la contraseña, he indicamos si el inicio de sesión fue con éxito o no, la verificación de la contraseña la hacemos con la misma lista. tendríamos dos usuarios de esta manera: usuarios[["usuarios","contraseña"],["admin","admin"]...,["n_usuarios","n_contraseñas"]]. en la opcion 2 guardamos los usuarios, hacemos un usuarios.append([]) para iniciar una lista dentro de la lista ya inicializada, y esto se repetirá siempre que queramos crear un nuevo usuario. y se guardara el usuario y la clave en la ultima posición que se verifica con el len(usuarios).

Espero te pueda servir, saludos.

```
opcion = 0
login = False
usuarios = []

while (opcion != 3):
    print("1. Iniciar Sesión")
    print("2. Registrar Usuario")
    print("3. Salir")

    try:
        opcion = int(input())

    except:
        print("Debe ingresar sólo números")

    if (opcion == 1):

        if not usuarios:
            print("Primero debe crear un usuario")

        else:
            user = input("Ingrese usuario: ")
            for user_in in usuarios:
                if user == user_in[0]:
                    login = True
                    password = input("Ingrese contraseña: ")

                    if password == user_in[1]:
                        print("Te has logeado con exito")
                    else:   
                        print("contraseña incorrecta")

            if login == False:
                print("No hemos encontrado tu usuario")

            login = False

    elif opcion == 2:
        print("opcion para registrar usuario")
        usuarios.append([])
        usuarios[len(usuarios)-1].append(input("Ingrese ususario: "))
        usuarios[len(usuarios)-1].append(input("Ingrese contraseña: "))
```